# Python: How to calculate sum of floats on csv

Tags: python, csv, sum

I'm starting to learn Python. How do I calculate the sum (float) of a certain column on csv file?

This is what I've done so far, but my code is not giving me the total of 'amount' (column):

```
giftFile = open('input.v0.small.csv')
giftReader = csv.reader(giftFile)
giftData = list(giftReader)

for row in giftReader:
    if len(row)>0:
        giftData += row['amount']

print('row 0:' + str(giftData[0]))
print("row 1's dollar value: " + str(giftData[1]))
```

Sample from csv-file:

```
date,amount,vendor,not sure,who,category
3/11/17, 100.00,"99 PLEDGCharlie S 99PLEDGES.COMAZ",2,Bob Smith,charity
3/11/17, 3.27,"CAFE BEARYUM ORO VALLEY AZ"
```

Comment: Can yuo show an example of your `csv` data?

Comment: It could be easily done with `pandas` lib

Comment: It would be lovely if you can provide the minimal version of the csv to reproduce the problem as well as the output that you got. It will help others to identify the cause and better suggest a solution.

Comment: Thanks....here you go.... (don't know if this minimal version will make sense) sorry, unable to attach csv her -- The task is to sum up the total of column [1] "amount" (100.00 + 3.27). There are blank rows in between the float rows:                                          
 date,amount,vendor,not sure,who,category

3/11/17, 100.00,"99 PLEDGCharlie S   99PLEDGES.COMAZ",2,Bob Smith,charity

3/11/17, 3.27,"CAFE BEARYUM    ORO VALLEY   AZ"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
import csv
from math import fsum

with open('input.v0.small.csv', 'r') as file:
    result = fsum(
        float(d['amount']) if d['amount'].strip() else 0
        for d in csv.DictReader(file) if d['amount']
    )
```

- Assumption: csv-file contains a header row and the column you want to sum up is named `amount`.
- Using a [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) instead of a `reader` to be able to fetch the amount by column name.
- Using [`fsum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum) instead of `sum`to avoid loss of precision.

Result for file

```
date,amount,vendor,not sure,who,category
3/11/17, 100.00,"99 PLEDGCharlie S 99PLEDGES.COMAZ",2,Bob Smith,charity
3/11/17, 3.27,"CAFE BEARYUM ORO VALLEY AZ"
```

is

```
103.27
```

Result for file

```
date,amount,vendor,not sure,who,category
3/11/17, 100.00,"99 PLEDGCharlie S 99PLEDGES.COMAZ",2,Bob Smith,charity


3/11/17, 3.27,"CAFE BEARYUM ORO VALLEY AZ"
```

is

```
103.27
```

Comment: I tried, but it gave me this error:   (added - print(result) at the end)                                                                                  result = fsum(float(d.get('amount', 0)) for d in csv.DictReader(file))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Comment: @Sandra There's something you're not telling us :) I've tried it with your sample and it works - see the edit?

Comment: @Sandra I've made some adjustments, maybe you could try them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with `sum`. `csv.reader` returns an iterable  giving a list for each row, so we just need to pick out the right column element, convert to a float, then add them all up. This example uses `Decimal` to give 'expected' results when summing floats, but you can use `float` instead if you prefer:

```
import csv
from decimal import Decimal

col = 1

with open('input.v0.small.csv') as giftFile:
    reader = csv.reader(giftFile)
    header = next(reader)
    print(sum(Decimal(x[col]) for x in reader if x[col]))
```

Simply change `col` to the number of the column to process.

Comment: I tried with Decimal and float, both were unsuccessful. Also, there is a title row, so the column 'amount' has the float numbers that I need to sum-up, and there are blank rows in between the amount rows.                                                                                                     Decimal:
    print(sum(Decimal(x[1]) for x in csv.reader(giftFile)))
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
 
float:
    print(sum(float(x[1]) for x in csv.reader(giftFile)))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'amount'

Comment: I've updated my answer to remove the header row, and also to ignore any empty values in the column.

Answer (score 0):

When opening files in Python, files should be closed. To avoid forgetting to close, use a context manager. After reading in your data as a list of lists, you could use a list comprehension to extract data from a specified column. Then, use the `sum` built-in function to perform the final summation.

```
from csv import reader

# context manager for reading-in CSV file 
with open('input.v0.small.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    data = list(csv_reader)

# list comprehension to extract specified column
ls = [float(row[1]) for row in data[1:]] 

# built-in sum function
column_sum = sum(ls)

# print result
print(f'Column sum is {column_sum}')
```

Comment: Hi Johnathan! I tried your solution but it gave me this error:  (I don't know what I'm doing wrong)                           
   column_sum = sum(ls)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Hello, Sandra. I do not have your original CSV file, unfortunately. I am only guessing what your original dataset looks like. Is the data stored as a string? I am wondering if I am adding the string column to the float data.

Comment: I have edited my code to reflect the situation where the first row in your dataset is stored as a string. Also, I used the `float()` function to cast the data as float, just in case.

Comment: I have updated the code to capture the 1-index column and all rows except the 0-index row.